# jquery animation works half the time

Tags: jquery, animation

I have three images of a door opening and closing the images are #scaryhall,#scaryhall2,and #scaryhall3. I've set it up where there's a div icon with zero opacity located at the door with a onclick function(). The function will check conditions and if true the present image will hide and a new image will show. The code I have below works, however sometimes when the div is clicked the function will trigger and sound will play and the colsole.log() will be displayed but the image will not change?
I've tried changeing the speed or timer of the image but that didn't fix the issue i've also tried running the same function twice but that also didn't work.

I'm not sure how to fix this issue, Like I've said the code works but at random times the image will freeze up or something.

```js
var Q = 0;
var light = 0;

function function_one() {
  console.log("functionone has been called.");
  Q = 2
}

function function_two() {
  console.log("function two has been called.")
  Q = 1
}

function hidemainoffice() {
  if (light === 0) {

    $("#scaryhall").hide(0.3);
    $("#scaryhall2").show(0.3); //NEEDS WORK//
    $("#halllight").hide(0.2);
    $("#halllight2").show(0.3);
    $("#scaryhall").stop();
    $("#scaryhall2").stop();
    function_one();
    fixedhidemainoffice();

  } else {

    light = 1;

    $("#scaryhall").hide(0.1);
    $("#scaryhall2").hide(0.1);
    $("#scaryhall3").show(0.2); //NEEDS WORK//
    $("#halllight").hide(0.1);
    $("#halllight2").show(0.2);
    $("#scaryhall").stop();
    $("#scaryhall2").stop();
    function_one()
    fixedhidemainoffice()
    console.log("else was triggerd.")
  }
}

function hidemainoffice2() {

  $("#scaryhall").show(0.2);
  $("#scaryhall2").hide(0.1);
  $("#halllight2").hide(0.1);
  $("#scaryhall3").hide(0.1); //NEEDS WORK// 
  $("#halllight").show(0.2);

  $("#scaryhall").stop();
  $("#scaryhall2").stop();

  function_two()
}

function hidemainoffice3() {
  if (Q === 2) {
    light = 1;
    $("#scaryhall3").show(0.2);
    $("#scaryhall2").hide(0.1); //NEEDS WORK //
    $("#halllight2").show(0.2);
    $("#halllight").hide(0.1);
    $("#halllight3").hide(0.1);
    $("#halllight3on").show(0.2);
    lightSwitch.play();
  } else {
    console.log("notworking!");
  }
}

function showlight() {
  if (Q === 2 && light === 1) {
    $("#scaryhall3").hide(0.1)
    $("#scaryhall2").show(0.2);
    $("#halllight3").show(0.2)
    lightSwitch.play();
    light = 0;
    console.log("light is on.");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="scaryhall" src="newmain1.jpg">
<img id="scaryhall2" src="newoffice1remake3.jpg">
<img id="scaryhall3" src="newofficelightsoff.jpg">


<div id="halllight" onmousedown="dooropen.play()" onclick="hidemainoffice()">HALLLIGHT</div>
<!-- HALL LIGHT -->
<div id="halllight2" onmousedown="doorclosenew .play()" onclick="hidemainoffice2()">halllight2</div>
<div id="halllight3" onclick="hidemainoffice3()">hallllight3</div>
<div id="halllight3on" onclick="showlight()">halllight3on</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you want to use portions of a millisecond with Show and Hide. I think you mean `300` milliseconds, or `0.3` seconds. See More: https://api.jquery.com/show/

```js
$(function() {
  var Q = 0;
  var light = 0;

  function one() {
    console.log("One has been called.", Q, light);
    Q = 2;
  }

  function two() {
    console.log("Two has been called.", Q, light);
    Q = 1;
  }

  function hideOffice(i) {
    $("img").hide(300);
    switch (i) {
      case 1:
        console.log("Action 1");
        playSound("dooropen");
        if (light === 0) {
          $("#scary-hall-2").show(300);
          $("#hall-light-1").hide();
          $("#hall-light-2").show();
          one();
        } else {
          light = 1;
          $("#scary-hall-3").show(300);
          $("#hall-light-1").hide();
          $("#hall-light-2").show();
          one();
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        console.log("Action 2");
        playSound("doorclosenew");
        $("#scary-hall-1").show(300);
        $("#hall-light-2").hide();
        $("#hall-light-1").show();
        two();
        break;
      case 3:
        console.log("Action 3");
        if (Q === 2) {
          light = 1;
          $("#scary-hall-3").show(300);
          $("#hall-light-2").show();
          $("#hall-light-1").hide();
          $("#hall-light-3").hide();
          $("#hall-light-3-on").show();
          playSound("lightswitch")
        } else {
          console.log("Not working!");
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  function showlight() {
    if (Q === 2 && light === 1) {
      $("#scary-hall-3").hide(100, function() {
        $("#scary-hall-2").show(200, function() {
          $("#hall-light-3").show(200);
        });
      });
      playSound("lightswitch");
      light = 0;
      console.log("light is on.");
    }
  }

  function playSound(n) {
    var s = $("<audio>", {
      src: n
    });
    //s.play();
  }

  $("div[id|='hall-light']").click(function() {
    var act = parseInt($(this).attr("id").slice(-1));
    console.log("Click", act);
    hideOffice(act);
  });

  $("#switch-light-3-on").click(showlight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="scary-hall-1" src="newmain1.jpg">
<img id="scary-hall-2" src="newoffice1remake3.jpg">
<img id="scary-hall-3" src="newofficelightsoff.jpg">

<div id="hall-light-1">Light 1</div>
<div id="hall-light-2">Light 2</div>
<div id="hall-light-3">Light 3</div>
<div id="switch-light-3-on">Light 3 On</div>
```

Your example is lacking too much to be able to identify what you are trying to accomplish. There's a lot of ways to animate it. Stacking the images on top of each other and then hiding one as needed to reveal the one behind it.

The best I can offer at this time is to clean up the code and show you some better practices that might help you. See code above.

Comment: Switching it to 300 didn't help. Also i found out that it's Firefox that's causing the issue. I have no issues with IE nor with Chrome. I tried switching to fadeToggle but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Lyle it might be related to the asynchronous execution of code. It's not clear what the issue is your seeing, you might want to  record the action. You can use the callback option for `.show()` and `.hide()` to execute once the show/hide is complete. This would string the callbacks to trigger one after another instead of all at once.